# .Net System.Timers.Timer: What happens if I use less than 1ms interval?

Tags: .net, timer

What happens if I set the interval on a System.Timers.Timer to .5 ?

This is some more text that I'm adding so the stupid filter will let me post this question.

Comment: Is there a reason your need less than a 1ms?  are you trying to do computerized trading?

Comment: I write software to simulate "warfare systems".. Very high speed warfare systems. Can't say much more without violating NDA's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, nothing.  In general, the timers within Windows are only accurate to a specific interval, somewhere around 15ms.  Anything smaller than that will normally just cause the timer to fire once every 14-15ms or so.

That being said, the framework isn't Windows-only.  On a different real time operating system, you could potentially get the timer to raise events more frequently than once every millisecond.  The framework API doesn't assume that you'll be dealing with the limitations of non-real time operating systems, even though practically this is the case (most of the time).

Note that, internally, `System.Timers.Timer` actually uses a `System.Threading.Timer` for its implementation, which uses an [Int32 for period and dueTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx).  As such, it is impossible for the Windows version to have non-integer timings.  The framework uses `Math.Ceiling` on the Interval passed, so you would get a 1ms interval.  That being said, this is an implementation detail, so not something that would or should be relied upon in general.

Comment: Good to know. Are there any realtime operating systems that currently support the .net framework?

Comment: @Justin984 Windows CE, but I have no idea whether the framework implementation there is the same as the normal framework, which would treat this as 1ms